# Rails form_for renders partial form_for to list values without submitting to DB, but now 2 submits

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, renderpartial

I have a simple display - form_for an application that renders another partial with form_for for displaying education qualifications. The partial is polymorphic. So, now I have 2 submits, the main submit simply doesn't respond and partial works....why?? Please note that code works well for one record but with pressing partial form submit. Please help.

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @application do |f| %>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading"> Education: </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <%= render partial: "degrees/form", :locals => { :degreeable => @application, :f => f }  %> <br>
        <%= f.link_to (fa_icon 'plus').to_s + " Add Another Qualification ", render(:partial => 'degrees/form', :locals => { :degreeable => @job, :f => f }), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Partial form_for is: (Note: I even took out submit and used a link_to on main form as shown above but still no effect.

```
<%= form_for [degreeable, Degree.new], :url => { :action => "index" } do |f| %>
  <div class = "form-group" }>
    <%= f.select :level, options_for_select(Application::EDUCATION, params[:level]), include_blank: "Select Degree", class: 'span-2' %>
    <%= f.text_field :description, :class => 'span5' %>
  </div>
 f.submit "Add Another Degree", class: 'btn btn-primary'
<% end %>
```

The desired behaviour must be:

1. partial displayed to show drop box with Bachelor/Master/Ph.D and
   another text field to accept name of qualification.
2. a button/link - 'Add more qualifications' to list qualifications without submitting to DB.
3. Only main form button should finally submit form for application into DB.

My questions to experienced developers:

1.Can AJAX in partial help list down on main form. if yes, how pls help. All AJAX code I find on SO and google submit in DB and not to simply list down.

2.Instead of reloading partial again with a button from main form can submit of partial help in simply listing down values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally did resolve it and this will be helpful for future visitors. By making 2 changes both ideas are credited to Stackoverflow developers for 2 different questions:-

1. [Form_for inputs and submit button in different partials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337647/form-for-inputs-and-submit-button-in-different-partials) - @Anand
2. [Rails passing form_for object to partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246540/rails-passing-form-for-object-to-partial) - @D.Patrick

Thx to both of you. So, finally my main form with render call now looks:

```
   <%= bootstrap_form_for @application do |f| %>
      *Many other application fields but irrelevant here.*
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"> Education: </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <% @form = f %>
          <%= render partial: "degrees/form", :locals => { :degreeable => @application, :f => @form }  %> <br>
          <%= f.link_to (fa_icon 'plus').to_s + " Add Another Qualification ", render(:partial => 'degrees/form', :locals => { :degreeable => @application, :f => f }), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary btn-outline btn-sm" %>
  <% end %>
```

and rendered partial form:

```
    <%= f.fields_for [degreeable, Degree.new], :url => { :action => "index" } do |ff| %>
  <div class = "form-group" }>
    <%= ff.select :level, options_for_select(JApplication::EDUCATION, params[:level]), include_blank: "Select Degree", class: 'span-2' %>
    <%= ff.text_field :description, :class => 'span5' %>
  </div>
   <% ff.submit "Add Another Degree", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

But am still stuck with JS/JQuery of click on button to list partial fields.Have posted the question [now on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443371/rails-js-button-onclick-to-re-render-partial-without-entering-into-db).

> UPDATE

:
I posted the complete answer at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42503139/rails-link-to-passing-form-for-object-instance-to-polymorphic-partial/43524994#43524994).